# How to never show the same card on a tinder app

Tags: ios, xcode, tinder

I am making a 'tinder' style app, and was wondering how I would make it so that once a card has been liked or disliked, then it won't be shown again to the user.  - I have seen that it has been asked before but the answer was no sufficient and was nearly 3 years ago :) -

Answer (score 1):

Make a flag for the ones that already appeared, something like a function that marks for each user like: alreadySeen() which receives a bool value or something and return if the value has already appeared.